# Scroll onClick using React.fowardRef is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref, js-scrollintoview

I would like to know how to use React `refs` to navigate to a specific component

```
function App() {
  let CompetencesRef = React.createRef();
  let ExperiencesRef = React.createRef();
  let FormationRef = React.createRef();
  let RecoRef = React.createRef();
  let refs = { CompetencesRef, ExperiencesRef, FormationRef, RecoRef }
  let scrollToRef = (reference) => {
    console.log(reference)
    reference.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
  }
  return (
    <ParallaxProvider>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div className="App">

          <div className="hero">
            <HeaderApp refs={refs} scrollToRef={scrollToRef} />
            <ApprochApp />
          </div>
          <Apropos />
          <Competences ref={CompetencesRef} />
          <Experiences ref={ExperiencesRef} />
          <Formation ref={FormationRef} />
          <Recom ref={RecoRef} />
          <Contact />
          <Footer />

        </div >
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ParallaxProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**AppHeader**

```
const AppHeader = (props, refs, scrollToRef) => {
    console.log(props)

    return (
        <div >
            <Headroom>
                <MenuApp refs={props.refs} scrollToRef={props.scrollToRef} />
            </Headroom>

        </div>

    )
}
export default AppHeader
```

**AppMenu**

```
const MenuApp = (props, refs, scrollToRef) => {
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <div className="menu sticky-inner grid-container">
            <div className="desktop-menu">
                <div className="menu-item a-propos" ref={props.refs.CompetencesRef} onClick={() => props.scrollToRef(props.refs.CompetencesRef)}>
                    <p className='button'>Compétences</p>
                </div>
                <div className="menu-item competences" ref={props.refs.ExperiencesRef} onClick={() => props.scrollToRef(props.refs.ExperiencesRef)} >
                    <p className='button'>Experiences </p>
                </div>
                <div className="menu-item experiences" ref={props.refs.FormationRef} onClick={() => props.scrollToRef(props.refs.FormationRef)}>
                    <p className='button'>Formation</p>
                </div>
                <div className="menu-item formation" ref={props.refs.RecoRef} onClick={() => props.scrollToRef(props.refs.RecoRef)}>
                    <p className='button'>Recomendations </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p className="mobile-menu">
                <MenuIcon />
            </p>
            <div className="github-ico">
                <GitHubIcon />
            </div>
            <div className="linkedin-ico">
                <LinkedInIcon />
            </div>
            <div className="contact">
                <div className='contact-btn'>
                    <span className="contact-ico"> <MessageIcon /></span>  <span style={isBrowser ? { display: 'block' } : { display: 'none' }} > contact </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default React.forwardRef(MenuApp)
```

I'm using a ClickHandler in Apps.js with `scrollIntoView`. But actually when I  click view does not scroll.

I would not use packages like [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll)

Comment: Where is the `forwardRef`? How you pass ref to `Competences` for example, please make a reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Oh I see it, thats not how `forwardRef` works, see docs

Comment: I think I'm using it like this example https://gist.github.com/jamesreggio/142215754ad06f375bd87657c6227ed8

Comment: Please make a normal sandbox, I dont understand how this code structured, where does `AppHeader` and `MenuApp` come from? How do you pass ref to `Competences` for example?

Comment: You can see in App.js where they came from. I have nested components

Comment: `AppHeader` === `HeaderApp`?...

Comment: Yes , sorry I have correct the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

First, there is a difference in using `ref` for function components and class components. Using `ref` on functional components will yield an unexpected result because they [don't have an instance](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs).

You should be using `forwardRef` for all section components and make sure the `ref` is placed on the wrapping element.

The second problem is that you are using the refs for two components. Refs should only be assigned to a single component (maybe not in all cases). In this case, you want a reference to the section components to get a hold on the HTML element.

So remove the `ref` props in the AppMenu component:

```
<div className="menu-item a-propos" onClick={() => props.scrollToRef(props.refs.CompetencesRef)}>
  <p className='button'>Compétences</p>
</div>
```

Although it will work with refs, you might be considering an easier setup. E.g. by using id's.

If you do want to keep using refs, I would also suggest that you don't pass the refs object to child components. You actually don't want the child component to "know" about higher components in the tree.

For example, you can mitigate this by handling the onClick callback in the App component.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimal reproducible example (without all code noise):

```
function App() {
  const competencesRef = React.useRef();
  const refs = { competencesRef /* ExperiencesRef, FormationRef, RecoRef */ };
  const scrollToRef = (reference) => {
    reference.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <AppHeader refs={refs} scrollToRef={scrollToRef} />
      <Competences ref={competencesRef} />
    </>
  );
}

const Competences = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <div ref={ref}>...</div>;
});

const AppHeader = (props) => {
  return <MenuApp refs={props.refs} scrollToRef={props.scrollToRef} />;
};

const MenuApp = (props) => {
  return (
    <div
      ref={props.refs.competencesRef}
      onClick={() => props.scrollToRef(props.refs.competencesRef)}
    >
      <p className="button">Compétences</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The problem with your code is that you use `React.createRef` instead of `React.useRef` (you can search for the differences), and you need `React.forwardRef` only for components using the `ref` prop like `Competences`.

Comment: Good catch, I've missed that one!

Comment: I don't know, if this is minimal code reproducible example, what's complicated one ? ref and forwardRef is so complicated for me.

Comment: I am trying to implement this solution in my project, but I don't understand

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your `scrollToRef` function:

```
window.scrollTo(0, reference.current.offsetTop);
```